# ORO CRM: Failed migrations by Composer install

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, orocrm, akeneo

I have a problem installing with the instructions (https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation/).

**This my environment:**

Operating system: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

MySql: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.38-MariaDB

```
Check system requirements
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Check   | Mandatory requirements                                                                                                                            |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| OK      | Vendor libraries must be installed                                                                                                                |
| OK      | app/cache/ or var/cache/ directory must be writable                                                                                               |
| OK      | app/logs/ or var/logs/ directory must be writable                                                                                                 |
| OK      | Configured default timezone "Europe/Berlin" must be supported by your installation of PHP                                                         |
| OK      | iconv() must be available                                                                                                                         |
| OK      | json_encode() must be available                                                                                                                   |
| OK      | session_start() must be available                                                                                                                 |
| OK      | ctype_alpha() must be available                                                                                                                   |
| OK      | token_get_all() must be available                                                                                                                 |
| OK      | simplexml_import_dom() must be available                                                                                                          |
| OK      | PCRE extension must be available                                                                                                                  |
| OK      | /tmp (sys_get_temp_dir()) directory must be writable                                                                                              |
| OK      | Maximum supported filename length must be greater or equal 242 characters. Make sure that the cache folder is not inside the encrypted directory. |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| Check   | PHP settings                               |
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| OK      | detect_unicode must be disabled in php.ini |
| OK      | string functions should not be overloaded  |
| OK      | memory_limit should be at least 512M       |
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Check   | Oro specific requirements                                                                  |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| OK      | PHP version must be at least 7.3.13 (7.3.19-1+0~20200612.60+debian8~1.gbp6c8fe1 installed) |
| OK      | GD extension must be at least 2.0                                                          |
| OK      | cURL extension must be at least 7.0                                                        |
| OK      | openssl_encrypt() should be available                                                      |
| OK      | iconv() must not return the false result on converting string "check string"               |
| OK      | intl extension should be available                                                         |
| OK      | zip extension should be installed                                                          |
| OK      | NodeJS is installed                                                                        |
| OK      | NodeJS ">=12.0" version must be installed.                                                 |
| OK      | NPM is installed                                                                           |
| OK      | public/uploads/ directory must be writable                                                 |
| OK      | public/media/ directory must be writable                                                   |
| OK      | public/bundles/ directory must be writable                                                 |
| OK      | var/attachment/ directory must be writable                                                 |
| OK      | var/import_export/ directory must be writable                                              |
| OK      | public/js directory must be writable                                                       |
| OK      | public directory must be writable                                                          |
| OK      | config/parameters.yml file must be writable                                                |
| OK      | UUID SQL function must be present                                                          |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Check   | Optional recommendations                                                        |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| OK      | Vendors should be installed in order to check all requirements.                 |
| OK      | PCRE extension should be at least version 8.0 (10.34 installed)                 |
| OK      | PHP-DOM and PHP-XML modules should be installed                                 |
| OK      | mb_strlen() should be available                                                 |
| OK      | utf8_decode() should be available                                               |
| OK      | filter_var() should be available                                                |
| OK      | posix_isatty() should be available                                              |
| OK      | intl extension should be available                                              |
| OK      | intl extension should be correctly configured                                   |
| OK      | intl ICU version should be at least 4+                                          |
| OK      | intl.error_level should be 0 in php.ini                                         |
| OK      | a PHP accelerator should be installed                                           |
| OK      | short_open_tag should be disabled in php.ini                                    |
| OK      | magic_quotes_gpc should be disabled in php.ini                                  |
| OK      | register_globals should be disabled in php.ini                                  |
| OK      | session.auto_start should be disabled in php.ini                                |
| OK      | PDO should be installed                                                         |
| OK      | PDO should have some drivers installed (currently available: mysql, sqlite)     |
| OK      | SOAP extension should be installed (API calls)                                  |
| WARNING | Install and enable the Tidy extension.                                          |
| WARNING | Disable Phar extension to reduce the risk of PHP unserialization vulnerability. |
| OK      | IMAP extension should be installed for valid email processing on IMAP sync.     |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I get the following error:

```
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migration\WarmUpEntityConfigCacheMigration - skipped

In MigrationExecutor.php line 116:

  Failed migrations: Oro\Bundle\ScopeBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroScopeBundleInstaller.
```

Does anyone else have the same problem or know how I can fix it?

Thanks

EDIT:

Info by: composer info | grep oro/

```
oro/calendar-bundle                  4.1.4              Calendar bundle for OroPlatform-based applications.
oro/commerce                         4.1.5              OroCommerce - an open-source Business to Business Commerce application. \nThis package con...
oro/commerce-crm                     4.1.2              OroCRM integration for OroCommerce
oro/crm                              4.1.5              OroCRM
oro/crm-call-bundle                  4.1.4              Oro Call Bundle
oro/crm-dotmailer                    4.1.4              Oro Dotmailer integration
oro/crm-hangouts-call-bundle         4.1.1              Oro Google Hangouts integration
oro/crm-magento-embedded-contact-us  4.1.1              OroCRM Magento Embedded Contact Us package
oro/crm-task-bundle                  4.1.3              Oro Task Bundle
oro/crm-zendesk                      4.1.2              OroCRM Zendesk Integration
oro/customer-portal                  4.1.5
oro/doctrine-extensions              1.2.2              Doctrine Extensions for MySQL and PostgreSQL.
oro/marketing                        4.1.3              Oro Marketing Bundles
oro/oauth2-server                    4.1.3              Oro OAuth 2.0 authorization and resource server for BAP
oro/platform                         4.1.5              Business Application Platform (BAP)
oro/platform-serialised-fields       4.1.1              OroPlatform Serialized Fields
oro/redis-config                     4.1.2              OroRedisConfigBundle
oro/twig-inspector                   1.0.3              Oro Twig Inspector adds the possibility to find twig templates and blocks used for renderi...
```

Comment: please share the output of `composer info | grep oro/ "

Comment: Please share more details - and explain how this is related to Linux, Composer, and Akeneo

Comment: You are using oro/platform 4.1.5 that is compatible only with MySQL 5.7 only. I recommend upgrading to 4.1.6 in order to get support for MySQL 8.0. As I said in an answer, MariaDB is not supported officially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially MariaDB is not supported. We recommend using Mysql 5.7+. For more details see [OroCRM system requirements](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/system-requirements/).

Anyway, if you choose to use MariaDB instead of MySQL, you should update to the latest version, because 10.0 is too old and unsupported.